# Shared classifier for 3 neural networks (is this weights sharing?)

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, classifier, vgg16, weight-initialization

I would like to create 3 different VGGs with a shared classifier. Basically, each of these architectures has only the convolutions, and then I combine all the nets, with a classifier.

For a better explanation, let’s see this image:

[image]

I have no idea on how to do this in Pytorch. Do you have any examples that can I study? Is this a case of weights sharing?

Edit: my actual code. Do you think is correct?

```
class VGGBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels,batch_norm=False):

        super(VGGBlock,self).__init__()

        conv2_params = {'kernel_size': (3, 3),
                        'stride'     : (1, 1),
                        'padding'   : 1
                        }

        noop = lambda x : x

        self._batch_norm = batch_norm

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,out_channels=out_channels , **conv2_params)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels) if batch_norm else noop

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=out_channels,out_channels=out_channels, **conv2_params)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels) if batch_norm else noop

        self.max_pooling = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))

    @property
    def batch_norm(self):
        return self._batch_norm

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        x = self.max_pooling(x)

        return x
```

```
class VGG16(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes=1,batch_norm=False):
    super(VGG16, self).__init__()

    self.in_channels,self.in_width,self.in_height = input_size

    self.block_1 = VGGBlock(self.in_channels,64,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    self.block_2 = VGGBlock(64, 128,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    self.block_3 = VGGBlock(128, 256,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    self.block_4 = VGGBlock(256,512,batch_norm=batch_norm)

  @property
  def input_size(self):
      return self.in_channels,self.in_width,self.in_height

  def forward(self, x):

    x = self.block_1(x)
    x = self.block_2(x)
    x = self.block_3(x)
    x = self.block_4(x)
    x = torch.flatten(x,1)

    return x
```

```
class VGG16Classifier(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, num_classes=1,classifier = None,batch_norm=False):
    super(VGG16Classifier, self).__init__()


    self._vgg_a = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
    self._vgg_b = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
    self._vgg_star = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
    self.classifier = classifier

    if (self.classifier is None):
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(2048, 2048),
          nn.ReLU(True),
          nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
          nn.Linear(2048, 512),
          nn.ReLU(True),
          nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
          nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        )

  def forward(self, x1,x2,x3):
      op1 = self._vgg_a(x1)
      op2 = self._vgg_b(x2)
      op3 = self._vgg_star(x3) 
      
      x1 = self.classifier(op1)
      x2 = self.classifier(op2)
      x3 = self.classifier(op3)

      return x1,x2,x3

      return xc
```

```
model1 = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
model2 = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
model_star = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
model_combo = VGG16Classifier(model1,model2,model_star)
```

EDIT: I changed the forward of VGG16Classifier, because previously I took the output of the 3 VGG, I made a concat, and I passed to a classifier. Instead, now we have the same classifier for each VGG.

Now, my question is, I want to implement this loss:
[image]
And here is my attempt of implementation:

```
class CombinedLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, loss_a, loss_b, loss_star, _lambda=1.0):
        super().__init__()
        self.loss_a = loss_a
        self.loss_b = loss_b
        self.loss_star = loss_star

        self.register_buffer('_lambda',torch.tensor(float(_lambda),dtype=torch.float32))


    def forward(self,y_hat,y):

        return (self.loss_a(y_hat[0],y[0]) + 
                self.loss_b(y_hat[1],y[1]) + 
                self.loss_combo(y_hat[2],y[2]) + 
                self._lambda * torch.sum(model_star.weight - torch.pow(torch.cdist(model1.weight+model2.weight), 2)))
```

Probably the part of lamba*sum is wrong, however, my question is, in this way, I have to split my dataset in 3 parts to obtain y[0], y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llgNj.png) and y[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffMaM.png), right?
If is not possible to ask in this post, I will create a new question.

Comment: You also want to train them parallely along with the classsifier? Or want to perform inference as shown in the diagram? Or both?

Comment: It would be nice to do both. Or better, do both to see which works better

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about what you actually want to know. You want to know how to create these networks and then train them as a single model? Or you have already trained these networks separately and now for testing you want to know how to build the inference pipeline?

Comment: I want to train them as a single model

Comment: @DevashishPrasad I am going to edit the post with the code I have already written. You can read and says what do you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems good but you are not taking any outputs from model1, model2 and model_star?

Here is how I would code this thing -

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class VGGBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels,batch_norm=False):
        super(VGGBlock,self).__init__()

        conv2_params = {'kernel_size': (3, 3),
                        'stride'     : (1, 1),
                        'padding'   : 1}

        noop = lambda x : x
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,out_channels=out_channels , **conv2_params)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels) if batch_norm else noop
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=out_channels,out_channels=out_channels, **conv2_params)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels) if batch_norm else noop
        self.max_pooling = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.max_pooling(x)

        return x

class VGG16(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes=1,batch_norm=False):
    super(VGG16, self).__init__()

    self.in_channels,self.in_width,self.in_height = input_size

    self.block_1 = VGGBlock(self.in_channels,64,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    self.block_2 = VGGBlock(64, 128,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    self.block_3 = VGGBlock(128, 256,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    self.block_4 = VGGBlock(256,512,batch_norm=batch_norm)

  @property
  def input_size(self):
      return self.in_channels,self.in_width,self.in_height

  def forward(self, x):

    x = self.block_1(x)
    x = self.block_2(x)
    x = self.block_3(x)
    x = self.block_4(x)
    x = torch.flatten(x,1)

    return x

class VGG16Classifier(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_classes=1, classifier=None, batch_norm=False):
    super(VGG16Classifier, self).__init__()

    self._vgg_a = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
    self._vgg_b = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
    self._vgg_c = VGG16((1,32,32),batch_norm=True)
    self.classifier = classifier

    if (self.classifier is None):
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(2048, 2048),
          nn.ReLU(True),
          nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
          nn.Linear(2048, 512),
          nn.ReLU(True),
          nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
          nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        )

  def forward(self,x1,x2,x3):
      op1 = self._vgg_a(x1)
      op2 = self._vgg_b(x2)
      op3 = self._vgg_c(x3)
      xc = torch.cat((op1,op2,op3),0)
      xc = self.classifier(xc)

      return xc

model = VGG16Classifier()
ip1 = torch.randn([1, 1, 32, 32])
ip2 = torch.randn([1, 1, 32, 32])
ip3 = torch.randn([1, 1, 32, 32])

# Model inference
print(model(ip1,ip2,ip3).shape) # torch.Size([3, 1])
```

Training also becomes straight forward, you can do it just like we do it for any other network. For eg defining optimizer like -

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
```

And similarly loss and optimizer steps also remains same -

```
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Thanks, i think it is right. Now, my question is: in this way we are training the model, as well as vgga, vggb and vggc? Because now i want to define a custom loss function in this way: "CrossEntropy_A + CE_B + CE_C + lambda*sum(weights(vgg_c)-(weights(vgg_a)+weights(vgg_b))^2). It is like an experiment of "offline" transfer learning in which I want to teach the model to sum the weights, so i want to be sure that in this way I am training the weights of all the architectures. Right?

Comment: Yes we are training all models. Pytorch builds the graph dynamically. And optimizer has model.parameters(), where model object has all models (vgga,vggb,vggc and classifier). For more details follow this thread https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-train-several-network-at-the-same-time/4920/4 . And lastly, you might want to print the model architecture. (may be using torchsummary package https://pypi.org/project/torch-summary/).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, I edited the question, because there was a mistake (my supervisor corrected me). And I have inserted also a question about the loss.

Comment: Do you have any advice?

Comment: Hi @CasellaJr, I not very good with maths. But I cannot understand the formula after ∑. ∑ means the summation of series over some index 'i' where 'i' can be 0 to N. So in your formula, what does 'i' means for wi* wib wia?

Comment: i means for each layer basically. But the point is not the formula, but how to split the dataset, and what to pass to the training then. Because basically i have 3 losses, a, b and star, so 3 y. I have to split in 3 the dataset?

Comment: I will suggest you to ask a new question with detailed elaboration.

Comment: Sure, I will make a new question

Comment: Ok, I have written a new question, thanks